# ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network, prediction

I trained a pretrained model with vgg19 on 9 classes. I saved the model and load it to predict on images into a folder. When I try to predict, I have this error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I declare my pretrained model like that:

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
model_name='VGG19'
base_model = VGG19(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', pooling="avg", include_top=False)
x=base_model.output
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(256, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.45, seed=123)(x)        
output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adamax(learning_rate=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After the training, I save the model and I load it:
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

```
#save the model
model.save('model_he.h5')
#load model
m=load_model('model_he.h5')
```

When I try to predict on the folder with my pretrained model, the error `Graph disconnected` appears.

```
import os

import cv2
import argparse
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

# Construct argument parser and parse the arguments
argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# First two arguments specifies our only argument "image" with both short-/longhand versions where either 
# can be used
# This is a required argument, noted by required=True, the help gives additional info in the terminal
# if needed
argument_parser.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to the input image")

# Set path to files
img_path = "val/"
files = os.listdir(img_path)
print("[INFO] loading and processing images...")

for filename in files:
    
    # Passing the entire path of the image file
    file= os.path.join(img_path, filename)
    
    # Load original via OpenCV, so we can draw on it and display it on our screen
    original = cv2.imread(file)

    image = image_utils.load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = image_utils.img_to_array(image)

    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = preprocess_input(image)


    print("[INFO] loading network...")
    

    print("[INFO] classifying image...")
    predictions = m.predict(image)   # Classify the image (NumPy array with 1000 entries)
    predictions = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=m.input, outputs=predictions)
    #P = decode_predictions(predictions)  # Get the ImageNet Unique ID of the label, along with human-readable label
    print(P)    

    # Loop over the predictions and display the rank-5 (5 epochs) predictions + probabilities to our terminal
    for (i, (imagenetID, label, prob)) in enumerate(P[0]):
        print("{}. {}: {:.2f}%".format(i + 1, label, prob * 100))

    original = cv2.imread(file)
    (imagenetID, label, prob) = P[0][0]
    cv2.putText(original, "Label: {}, {:.2f}%".format(label, prob * 100), (10, 30), 
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow(original)  
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is `x` in the line `predictions = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)` ? Shouldn't it be `predictions` instead of `x`?

Comment: @AndrzejO, yes you are right, i removed the x in predictions but it does not resolve my issue